# Difference between tensorflow versions

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently following tutorials on Udemy on tensorflow (quite new to this). The tutorials are based off of an older version i.e 1.3.

As far as I have read, one of the major changes introduced in the newer version i.e 1.13 is eager execution. That session.run() etc. is old now. Should I be concerned ...maybe ask for a refund?

Comment: No TensorFlow version 1.13 has been released yet. Eager was introduced some versions ago, and it is still more less experimental. In the future (TensorFlow 2), eager will be more important, but both modes (graph and eager) will still be relevant and fully supported (and, depending on the case, you may prefer one or the other). `session.run` is not "old now", it is still the main interface for evaluation (directly or indirectly, e.g. through `eval`). In any case, nearly everything you learn for graph mode will be applicable to eager.

Comment: On a side note though, 1.3 *is* pretty old. Things such as input pipelines, model building, distributed training, etc have changed *massively* since then.